# I get Error when upload laravel to host server

Tags: laravel

I was getting this error after upload project to the host server

> "The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your
>   PHP installation"

then after seeking the solution it disappear then this appear I don't know how to fixed it

> "Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController not
>   defined"

Comment: Same problem in local today. I just add 2 fields in datatable and then bing. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

In your server console run :

```
php artisan optimize
```

That way you clear your routes/cache

This will solve the issue you are mentioning

Comment: Sorry after optimize I need to upload whole project or which part I need to upload via ftp?thanks

Comment: Your project is there already just access your routes, you can not run artisan commands without having a laravel project in place.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on laravel 6

solotion is

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=flare-config`

and in `config/flare.php` Update

```
'reporting' => [
        'anonymize_ips' => true,
        'collect_git_information' => false,
        'report_queries' => true,
        'maximum_number_of_collected_queries' => 200,
        'report_query_bindings' => true,
        'report_view_data' => true,
    ],

'send_logs_as_events' => false,
```